# JQuery reset function $('#form').get(0).reset(); is not working on modal popup button?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The `$('#form').get(0).reset();` is not working on Modal pop up submit button click. It gives me error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).reset is not a function

Can anyone please suggest me where I am going wrong.

View code

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "form" }))
                {

                    <button type="button" id="All" class="btn btn-info">Read</button>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="Confirm" role="dialog">
                            <div id="dialogbox" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">                                   
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"  data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                                       <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" >Yes</button>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                }
```

Script

```
$('#All').click(function () {
                $("#Confirm").modal('show');
            });


$(document).ready(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
            $('#form').submit(function () {
                  if (!$(this).valid()) {
                    return;
                   }
                 $.post(url,$(this).serialize(), function (response) {
                     if (response.success) {
                      $('#form').get(0).reset();
                     }
                     else {
                         var message = response.message;
                         alert(message);
                      }
                });
                   return false;
               })
        });
```

Comment: Try `$('#form')[0].reset();`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, I tried that as well. But the error still same.

Comment: in the response.success handler, put a breakpoint and see what's the output of $('#form'). By opening up the DOM chain, you can figure out where is the issue and the correct query to be invoked